# User connection to another User as a friend relationship - AWS GraphQL Transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS GraphQL Transform to build my schema, and I can't find any resources that point me to how I make a connection between one user and another without creating another type object.

```
   type User @model)
{
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    friends: [User] @connection(name: "UserFriendConn")
    blockedUsers: [User] @connection(name: "UserBlockedConn")
    friendRequests: [User] @connection(name: "UserFriendRequestConn")
}
```

Calling *amplify api gql-compile* will throw error: **InvalidDirectiveError: Found one half of connection "UserFriendConn" at User.friends but no related field on type User**.

Am I applying an entirely wrong pattern here?

Comment: The `@connection` directive enables you to specify relationships between `@model` types(plural). You cant use self-connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your connections should look like. Given that your other types are:

Friend

BlockedUser

FriendRequest

```
type User @model) {
id: ID!
email: String!
password: String!
friends: [Friend] @connection(name: "UserFriendConn")
blockedUsers: [BlockedUser] @connection(name: "UserBlockedConn")
friendRequests: [FriendRequest] @connection(name: "UserFriendRequestConn")
```

}

Comment: Thank you. This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: @EirikStubMo I am having the same issue right now so i ended up doing the same , however could you provide an example how the other connection type schema should look for example the the "Friends" model